# Typo3 CKeditor <iframe> YouTube video issue

Tags: php, iframe, youtube, typo3

I tried to add an YouTube video in my text/image content with the iframe link from YouTube, or by clicking in "Embed Youtube video" and adding the embed code but it doesn't work, in frond en I see an Iframe balise like :

<--iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dqsdsdq" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>

In Ckeditor I see a black square of YouTube written : video not available

I checked my config but I don't see what is wrong, I show you some code of my config :

Default.yaml

```
editor:
  config:
    allowedContent: true
    removeFormatAttributes: ""
    youtube_width: 550
    extraAllowedContent: '*(*)[data-*]; iframe'


   externalPlugins:
    youtube: {resource: "EXT:skin/Resources/Public/vendor/scripts/youtube/youtube/plugin.js"}

    extraAllowedContent:
      - span
      - iframe
    allowTags:
      - iframe
  processing:
    allowTags:
      - iframe
    allowTagsOutside:
      - iframe
```

Page.ts :

```
RTE.default {
    proc {
        blockElementList := addToList(iframe)
        externalBlocks := addToList(iframe)
    }
}
```

PageTemplate.ts

```
lib.parseFunc_RTE.allowTags := addToList(object,param,embed,iframe)
lib.parseFunc.htmlSanitize = 0
lib.parseFunc_RTE.htmlSanitize = 0
```

Someone can tell we what's wrong with my config ?  I'm using TYPO3 9.5

thanks you

update : It's working now, I added the 2 last line in my PageTemplate.ts , I edited my code to show my fix

Comment: I'd strongly advise rather use textmedia default tt_content element, as this allows better maintainability. There, instead of an image you can add the public youtube url and let your system config handle everything (e.g. GDPR, PreviewImages, sizes etc). 
So this approach is quite cheap and more maintainable than allowing iframe in RTE.
I know this sounds not helpful, but being at the same problem with a 30k pages install switching every RTE content with youtube iframe to a proper textmedia during the 9LTS upgrade was faster than telling the RTE to allow these. That's why I rather mention it.

Comment: Yeah I understand, but it's for a website with already a lot of text/image content that's why I have to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
editor:
  externalPlugins:
    youtube: {resource: "EXT:image_displayer/Resources/Public/youtube/plugin.js"}
    typo3image:
      allowedExtensions: "jpg,jpeg,png"
   
  config:
    allowTags:
      - pre
      - code
      - iframe
    allowedContent: true
    removePlugins: null

processing:
  allowTags:
    - pre
    - code
    - iframe    
  allowedContent: true
  removeFormatAttributes: ""
  youtube_width: 550
```

It can be possible you need a youtube plugin also

get plugin: https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/youtube

Put the plugin in custom_ext/Resources/Public/CKEditor/Plugins/youtube/ folder

Also:

Paste the embed code in the source view of the editor, maybe instead of using the youtube button.

This line is also needed:

```
lib.parseFunc_RTE.allowTags := addToList(object,param,embed,iframe)
```

Comment: I tried your settings, and I already have the YouTube plugin, I edited my post to show you what I did, and it still doesn't works

Comment: I got it working on my test site with config i just changed the answer

Comment: I tried and doesn't works, I'm starting to wonder if it's a config problem

Comment: Did you include ext:skin in your template includes?

Comment: yes I included that but I solved my issue, I added lib.parseFunc.htmlSanitize = 0
lib.parseFunc_RTE.htmlSanitize = 0 in my code, and for the black square on the editor, it was because of safari, no issue with chrome